# Variable me regresa null

Tags: java, android

Tengo un problema, necesito que al momento de dar clic en guardar se envíe la url de la imagen que subí a cloudinary,la imagen si se sube pero no se por que me regresa null, el código en si no regresa error, en este log  **Log.d("Ruta en botón guardar",String.valueOf(ruta));** me doy cuenta que manda null cualquier ayuda seria genial muchas gracias

```
public class edit_profile_activity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
    String imgDecodableString;
    Button btngudar;
    Map uploadResult;
String ruta;
    Uri selectedImage;
    Map config = new HashMap();
    ImageView imgView;

    Button bu=null, guardar;


    EditText editName, editEmail, editLastName, editNick, showDate;
    TextView txtNameTop, txtNickTop;
    RadioButton rbMale,rbFemale;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);

        //bu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
        guardar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnguardar);
        rbMale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbMale);
        rbFemale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbFemale);

        config.put("cloud_name", "*********");
        config.put("api_key", "1234567890abcde");
        config.put("api_secret","123456789012345678901234567");

        new PlifRequestBase(edit_profile_activity.this) {

            @Override
            public JsonObject onHttpOk(JsonObject response) throws JSONException {
                JsonObject data;
                data = response;

                //En esta parte se declaran los botones, textos y campos de texto con las respectivas variables
                rbMale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbMale);
                rbFemale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbFemale);

                editLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editapellido);
                editEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editcorreo);
                editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editnombre);
                editNick = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editnick);
                showDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.showDate);


                txtNameTop = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNombreA);
                txtNickTop = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nickname);

                //se toman los valores desde el JsonObject
                final String name = data.get("first_name").getAsString();
                final String lastName = data.get("last_name").getAsString();
                final String emailUser = data.get("email").getAsString();
                //final String nick= data.get("nick").getAsString();
                //final String nick= data.get("nick").toString();
                //final String nick= String.valueOf(data.get("nick").getAsString().equals(""));
                final String nick = data.get("nick") != JsonNull.INSTANCE ? data.get("nick").getAsString() : null;
                final int sex = data.get("sex").getAsInt();

                //se ponen en los respectivos textos y edit text lo consultado
                edit_profile_activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        txtNameTop.setText(name + " " + lastName);
                        //txtNickTop.setText(nick);
                        editName.setText(name);
                        editEmail.setText(emailUser);
                        editLastName.setText(lastName);
                        if (nick == null)
                        {
                            editNick.setText("");

                        }
                        if(nick != "false") {
                            editNick.setText(nick);
                        }
                        //    showDate.setText(birthDate);
                    }
                });

                Log.d("Nombre", name + " " + lastName);
                Log.d("Correo", emailUser);


                return data;
            }

            @Override
            public void onHttpCreate(JsonObject response) throws JSONException {

            }

            @Override
            public void onHttpUnprocessableEntity(JsonObject response) throws JSONException {
                this.cancel(true);
                final String error = response.get("errors").toString();
                edit_profile_activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(edit_profile_activity.this.getApplicationContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }.execute("user/profile", "GET");

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        //se hacen los cambios en la api a partir de la accion del boton guardar
        guardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(config);
                            uploadResult =  cloudinary.uploader().upload(imgDecodableString, ObjectUtils.emptyMap());
                            ruta = String.valueOf(uploadResult.get("url"));
                            Log.d("Ruta",String.valueOf(ruta));
                            Log.d("RESULTADOS",String.valueOf(uploadResult));
                            Log.d("URL",String.valueOf(uploadResult.get("url")));

                        } catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                thread.start();

                Log.d("Ruta en boton guardar",String.valueOf(ruta));

                String setName = editName.getText().toString();
                String setEmail= editEmail.getText().toString();
                String setLastName= editLastName.getText().toString();
                String setNick = editNick.getText().toString();
                String setBirthDate= showDate.getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(edit_profile_activity.this, "Se ha guardado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (setNick == null)
                {
                    editNick.setText("nickname");

                }
                if(setNick != "")
                {
                    editNick.setText("");
                }

                int sex = 0;

                if (rbMale.isChecked())
                {
                    sex=1;
                }
                else if (rbFemale.isChecked())
                {
                    sex=2;
                }else
                {
                    sex=3;
                }

                new PlifRequestBase(edit_profile_activity.this){

                    @Override
                    public JsonObject onHttpOk(JsonObject response) throws JSONException {
                        JsonObject data;
                        data = response;
                        if (response.equals(200)){
                            Toast.makeText(edit_profile_activity.this, "Se ha guardado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        return data;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onHttpCreate(JsonObject response) throws JSONException {


                        try {
                            Toast.makeText(edit_profile_activity.this, "Se ha guardado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onHttpUnprocessableEntity(JsonObject response) throws JSONException {
                        this.cancel(true);
                        final String error = response.get("errors").toString();
                        edit_profile_activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(edit_profile_activity.this.getApplicationContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                        });

                    }

                }.execute("user/profile","PUT","user",
                        "email", setEmail,
                        "first_name", setName,
                        "last_name", setLastName,
                        "nick", setNick,
                        "birthdate", setBirthDate,
                        "sex", String.valueOf(sex),
                        "current_avatar", String.valueOf(ruta)
                );

                Log.d("Envía:", setBirthDate);
                Log.d("Sexo", String.valueOf(sex));

                    new PlifRequestBase(edit_profile_activity.this) {

                    @Override
                    public JsonObject onHttpOk(JsonObject response) throws JSONException {
                        JsonObject data;
                        data = response;

                        //En esta parte se declaran los botones, textos y campos de texto con las respectivas variables
                        rbMale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbMale);
                        rbFemale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbFemale);

                        editLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editapellido);
                        editEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editcorreo);
                        editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editnombre);
                        editNick = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editnick);

                        txtNameTop = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNombreA);
                        txtNickTop = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nickname);

                        //se toman los valores desde el JsonObject
                        final String name = data.get("first_name").getAsString();
                        final String last_name = data.get("last_name").getAsString();
                        final String email_user = data.get("email").getAsString();
                        //final String nick= data.get("nick").toString();
                        //final String nick= String.valueOf(data.get("nick").getAsString().equals(""));
                        final String nick = data.get("nick") != JsonNull.INSTANCE ? data.get("nick").getAsString() : null;
                        final int sex = data.get("sex").getAsInt();

                        //se ponen en los respectivos textos y edit text lo consultado
                        edit_profile_activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                txtNameTop.setText(name + " " + last_name);
                                //txtNickTop.setText(nick);
                                editName.setText(name);
                                editEmail.setText(email_user);
                                editLastName.setText(last_name);
                                if (nick == null)
                                {
                                    editNick.setText("");

                                }
                                if(nick != "false") {
                                    editNick.setText(nick);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        Log.d("Nombre", name + " " + last_name);
                        Log.d("Correo", email_user);


                        return data;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onHttpCreate(JsonObject response) throws JSONException {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onHttpUnprocessableEntity(JsonObject response) throws JSONException {
                        this.cancel(true);
                        final String error = response.get("errors").toString();
                        edit_profile_activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(edit_profile_activity.this.getApplicationContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }.execute("user/profile", "GET");


            }
        });

    }


    public void logout(View view){
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("PlifMx", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        Intent intent = new Intent(edit_profile_activity.this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }


    public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
        // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        // Start the Intent
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
    }
    public void subirImg ()
    {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                final ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circleImageView);
                // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
                imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No seleccionaste una imagen",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ocurrio algo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: deberías despersonalizar tus credenciales antes de publicar tu código ;)

Answer (score 0):

Revisa en `debug` si tienes una `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. No he usado Cloudinary, pero supongo que `uploader().upload(...)` toma acceso al internet.

Si es así vas a tener que poner este código en un [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) para funcionar.
La razón es que Android ya desde 3.0 no permite acceso directo a la red en la hebra principal.

Comment: jajaja no me di cuenta de mis credenciales, gracias, y gracias por el tip ahorita lo checo con el AsynTask :)

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que estas usando un Thread para obtener el valor de `ruta`,  si ejecutas un Thread e inmediatamente de iniciarlo deseas obtener este valor, puede ser que aún no haya terminado la petición y la obtención del valor, lo recomendable es realizarlo dentro de la definición del Thread.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(config);
                            uploadResult =  cloudinary.uploader().upload(imgDecodableString, ObjectUtils.emptyMap());
                            ruta = String.valueOf(uploadResult.get("url"));
                            Log.d("Ruta",String.valueOf(ruta));
                            Log.d("RESULTADOS",String.valueOf(uploadResult));
                            Log.d("URL",String.valueOf(uploadResult.get("url")));


//*** obten aquí en valor.
Log.d("Ruta en boton guardar",String.valueOf(ruta));

                        } catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                thread.start();

               // Log.d("Ruta en boton guardar",String.valueOf(ruta));
```